# Cannot access my Hotmail inbox

Tags: outlook.com

I basically abandoned the Hotmail account a few years ago, but I need to see an email for password reset & Twitter. It is now Outlook and I have nothing in the inbox, and can't see a way to get them.

Answer (score 5):

> Free Windows Live Hotmail accounts become inactive if you don't sign in for more than 270 days or within the first 10 days after signing up for an account. After an account becomes inactive, all messages, folders, and contacts are deleted. Incoming messages will be sent back to the sender as undeliverable. Your account name is still reserved. However, if the account stays inactive for an additional 90 days, the account name may be permanently deleted.

- [Microsoft community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-orestoremail/deleted-hotmail-account-due-to-inactivity-i-need/252611c1-94d6-4b48-974c-005038ea46f7).

Since you abandoned it "years" ago, pretty sure it got wiped.